# How to Create Bulid on Production Server of Jhipster Project

Tags: spring, angularjs, maven, gruntjs, jhipster

i am working on project using jhipster(angularjs,maven,Grunt) can you help me how to create it bulid on Production server using tomcat7 with jdk 1.7.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation : http://jhipster.github.io/production.html

1. Do a "mvn package -Pprod"
2. Use the ".orginial" WAR file
3. Deploy it to Tomcat, and voilà :-)